# How to include a base64 encoded PDF in the response to a slash command?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I want to send a slash command (e.g. /getPDF) to my server and return a pdf as a base64 string.

Preferably the pdf should be presented as a file on the clients side.

I tried including it as an image URL in the answer and a title url but that doesn't work.

Is this possible at all or do I have to manually upload my pdf to, say, Google Drive and then send the link as a response to the slash command?

Any other way this could work? With a bot maybe?

Answer (score 1):

PDFs are treated as normal files by Slack, so there will not be automatically unfurled like image files.

I can think of 2 possible solutions to your issue:

**Upload PDF file**

The most straightforward solution would be to upload the requested PDF file to the Slack workspace and share it with the user with [`files.upload`](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload). Either in the channel where the slash command was issued are in a direct message channel.

This would be the most convenient approach for the user, but would require your app to possess some advanced scopes and rights to a workspace. Also keep in mind that you would need to handle slash commands running for more than 3 seconds if your PDFs are large.

**Download link**

Another approach would be to present the user with a download link in reply to the slash command. This could be a text link in the reply message or a [link button](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-attachments#link_buttons).

Note that you can not include a [download link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_download_link.asp) in a link button, so the link button would need to point your app, which then in turn can redirect to a download link.

You could also include a preview for the PDF file along with the download link.

If you want to check out an example for downloading a PDF via link button, check out the Slack app [Easy Poll](https://www.kalkoken.org/apps/easypoll/web/). Once a poll is completed the user is presented with a download button to retrieve a PDF copy of the voting result chart.

Full disclosure: I am the author of Easy polls.